# Can't install the project after added Prerequisites NET 4.6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I used Visual Installer project to deploy.

After I added .NET 4.6 components to my project and built it, I didn't got click to install option, to check this in Visual studio.

But after deleting this everything worked again.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Download Prerequisites***: I would set the prerequisite to download from the vendor's web site - that is the first option of those 3 in your screen shot - at least in my English Visual Studio Setup Project. I don't read Russian / Cyrillic I am afraid. Those letters really look like an alien language :-).

***Eliminate Embedded Prerequisites*** (for common runtimes): My rant about including the .NET framework is generally that what you include is **`1)`** outdated in no time with all the security fixes (hence bloating your setup for no reason?) and **`2)`** the new Windows OS versions are including .NET pre-installed outright (albeit perhaps not in the correct version). **`3)`** .NET is also installed via Windows Update now - for home users (eventually, there is some delay in release), and **`4)`** corporate packagers absolutely hate pulling packages apart to remove common runtimes since they have to use standard corporate packages for these runtimes and are not allowed to use the bundled ones. Just a report from those who receive vendor setups. Keep it simple. Prefer to document what your setup does? Providing simple **`Readme.txt`** or **`Deployment Info.pdf`** is good. Delivering a special setup for corporations and large scale deployment is another good way to do it (just a zip of prerequisites and the actual setup).

***Launch Condition***: A simple launch condition telling the user to install the .NET framework and what version might be enough, but maybe your "download from vendor site" is best?

---

***.NET Runtime***: As a side-note - and I guess this is well known for most - just pointing it out to whoever might read this: There have been way fewer versions of the **.NET runtime** (**CLR**) than is commonly perceived. *`There is the framework, and then there is the runtime`*. Please see .NET expert and overall computer expert [Hans Passant's summary here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10594278/129130) (and the other answers on the page too). [One more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802329/129130). Version 1.0 and 1.1 of the CLR would seem to be largely irrelevant by now?

***Alternative Tools***: [I have long disliked Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893). Just throwing in a link to [alternative MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130).

Comment: Thanks for response, but this App will be using on old machine and OS (Win 7 x32 or x64 maybe Win 10 x64) and I dont know will be have than a new NET 4.6 or not. Client said that I need to put this Framework to Application, that it will not meet any errors about it, and on machine dont have a internet! yes No internet!. I use Installer project because its simple to create a Client Installer from UI diagram in VS

Comment: Oh, special case then. I suppose you could download the runtime and put it next to your main MSI? Or wrap it in a zip archive? Commercial tools have much better options for runtimes (Advanced Installer, Installshield, etc...).

Comment: yes I download NET 4.6 and try to Put it in my project but no sucess(I mean its not appear while installing Client application and not check version on PC and on my App). Comertial must be buy but my PM said it not necessary, using free tools

Comment: Could you add a launch condition that tells the user to run the .NET 4.6 if needed? [How to detect .NET framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) and then just leave the .NET installer next to your setup in a zip? WiX can certainly do this for you using their Burn feature (setup.exe bundles).

Comment: OK thanks,I will see it, but I cant using installer class and action in installer project.I try to use WIX but its so hard to undestand xml and rules how to correct create install packet with some validating conditions, becaus I stay on this

Comment: I have this [WiX Quick-Start answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).

Comment: [Crash course sample on how to make a Burn bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065074/sql-server-named-instance-with-visual-studio-2017-installer-project/52071758#52071758) (a WiX made setup.exe - with embedded prerequisites).

Comment: Great, good luck. Visual Studio Installer projects [tend to fail for people eventually if they get new requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936435/visual-studio-publish-project-into-one-simple-installer/47944893#47944893) . Just from practical, real-world experience.

Comment: I still cant vote to up your reputation :( , Oh Now I Can =)!

Comment: No worries, I think you need 50 or so. You can set the answer accepted though - I think. But I guess it isn't a final answer yet.